# XML Import txt file to to SQL. Duplicate id error message?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2017

My administrative program uses an xml-file to import pricelists (txt files) to the SQL database.
There is a lot of rows in the XML file but this is the rows I have problems with.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<BCPFORMAT>
<RECORD>
<FIELD ID="41" xsi:type="CharFixed"  LENGTH="5"  COLLATION=""/>
</RECORD>
<ROW>
<COLUMN SOURCE="41" NAME="VGRNR1" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
<COLUMN SOURCE="41" NAME="VGRNR2" xsi:type="SQLVARYCHAR"/>
</ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

I have changed the eighth row to COLUMN SOURCE="41" because I want the data from FIELD ID="41" in both fields VGRNR1 and VGRNR2 in the SQL database.
When I make the change I get this error message from my administrative program:

> duplicate element id "41"

Is it possible to edit the xml-file so I can get data from FIELD ID="41" in both fields VGRNR1 and VGRNR2 in the database?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Are you using a **BCPFORMAT** format XML file by any chance? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/xml-format-files-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15